# Intercept wcf request/response programmatically

Tags: wcf, wcf-binding, wcf-security, wcf-data-services

I have a contract first wcf services... I want to capture the raw soap request/response @ the server programmatically and polish them before saving to the database. I need this process for some auditing purposes. How to do this?
**Note: I don't want to do this with wcf tracing by configuring in web.config file.**

Comment: Just curious - why don't you want to use tracing?

Comment: @TadDonaghe : Probably just like me he need them for others, BTW is it possible to trace the raw messages and save them? I am expecting that sometimes the response sent back will not be what the wcf proxy class expects as service team has been known to break contracts and change wsdl's after development cycle, need to grab the raw request/response.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may implement your own [Messageinspector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa717047.aspx), I´m not sure if this is enough for you but its worth a try.

Answer (score 1):

I think you could use the [SOAP extension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188761.aspx)

Another solution could be writing a custom `HttpModule` where you will be able to manipulate the request before it reach the .net engine

```
public class LogModule : IHttpModule
{
    public void Init(HttpApplication context)
    {
        context.BeginRequest += this.OnBegin;
    }

    private void OnBegin(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpApplication app = (HttpApplication)sender;
        HttpContext context = app.Context;

        byte[] buffer = new byte[context.Request.InputStream.Length];
        context.Request.InputStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        context.Request.InputStream.Position = 0;

        string soapMessage = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer);

        // Do something with soapMessage
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: your soap extension link is broken.

Comment: SOAP Extensions (and HttpModule) are specific to asmx services, not WCF services ([Avoid the use of SOAP extensions when developing new ASMX services that will be migrated to WCF...](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff699410.aspx))